# How to call restful service with args in asp.net web form?

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, rest, webforms

I want to use from Restful service in asp.net webform and C#. So I used HttpWebRequest and I could got Token successfully. But I can't call Restful service with parameter. Using this code I tried to send BrokerId as a parameter but I think this is wrong because that service show error authorization:

```
private void RemainInq(string Auth)
{
string Address = @"http://10.19.252.21:5003/Rest/Topup/RemainCreditInquiry";
Uri UriAddress = new Uri(Address);
var PostParam = "BrokerId=13000303";
var data = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(PostParam);
HttpWebRequest req = WebRequest.Create(UriAddress) as HttpWebRequest;
req.Method = "POST";
req.ContentType = "application/json";
req.Accept = "gzip,deflate";
req.ContentLength = data.Length;
req.Host = "10.19.252.21:5003";
req.Headers.Add("Authorization", Auth);
req.ContentLength = data.Length;
using (var strem = req.GetRequestStream())
{
strem.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
}
HttpWebResponse resp = req.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse;
Encoding enc = System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding(1252);
StreamReader loResponseStream = new StreamReader(resp.GetResponseStream(), enc);
string Response = loResponseStream.ReadToEnd();
string[] s = Response.Split(',');
for (int i = 0; i < s.Count(); ++i)
s[i] = s[i].Substring(s[i].IndexOf(":") + 2, s[i].LastIndexOf('"') - 
s[i].IndexOf(":") - 2);
loResponseStream.Close();
resp.Close();
}
```

Comment: Hi, iman. I think your authorization is not valid for the server. Can you tell which unAuthorize code did you get?

Comment: Try this code:
req.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + Auth);

I am assuming the server is authorizing using OAuth

Comment: @Iman, I think you did it right, Are you sure you have access to RemainCreditInquiry with one parameter?

Comment: Which authorization failed code did you get? If you get 403 error code, it means the user didn't have access to RemainCreditInquiry method with one parameter or if you get 401 error code, it means the authentication data that you send it to the server is not valid.

Comment: And also please remove your basic authentication information. it's encoded by base64-encoding and easily can decode.

Answer (score 2):

Finally I could find answer.

```
private string[] CallSaleProvider(string YourParam1,string YourParam2)

    {

        var httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://YourAddress");

        httpWebRequest.ContentType = "application/json";

        httpWebRequest.Method = "POST";

        httpWebRequest.Headers.Add("Authorization", Auth);

        using (var streamWriter = new

        StreamWriter(httpWebRequest.GetRequestStream()))

        {

            string json = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(new

            {

                YourParam=Value, YourParam=value,YourParam=value


            });

            streamWriter.Write(json);

        }

        string result;

        var httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)httpWebRequest.GetResponse();

        using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(httpResponse.GetResponseStream()))

        {

            result = streamReader.ReadToEnd();

        }

        string[] s = result.Split(',');

        for (int i = 0; i < s.Count(); ++i)

            s[i] = s[i].Substring(s[i].IndexOf(":") + 2, s[i].LastIndexOf('"') - s[i].IndexOf(":") - 2);


        httpResponse.Close();

        return s;

    }
```